# SAML based SSO for Authentication and LDAP for authorization - Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring-security, ldap, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, google-workspace

Using Gsuite with Cloud Identity Premium

a) Initialized GSuite as iDP as SAML app for SSO
b) Secure LDAP client for reading user information and group information for authorization.

Really confused how to register LDAP client (as authorization provider) along with SAML SSO (authentication provider).

Comment: Please note LDAP needs to be connected with certificate and not username and password

Comment: What did yout try so far?

Comment: SAML SSO works fine ... don't know how to register LDAP ... all examples are based on authentication ... nothing like a Authn via SAML and Authz via LDAP (although it looks an obvious choice)

Comment: So, you obviously did not try anything so far.

Comment: I did add the certificates to the /resource/cert folder and register them, but then could not figure out the myriad complexity of how to test the connectivity

Comment: Finally got the connection working ... ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.google.com:636 -b dc=xxxx,dc=xx -x -s sub -x "(ObjectClass=*)"

Comment: Also installed jxplorer for visualized the directory ... and it worked fine after importing the certificates.

Comment: @Michael-O The problem is now with Java ... when I try to search nothing come back. The baseDN can only be set this DC=XXX,DC=com ... if I try to give OU in the prefix string it throws an error. String domain = "dc=xxxx,dc=com"; works fine ... but if I give String domain = "ou=users,dc=xxxx,dc=com"; it gives an error [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'ou=users,dc=xxxx,dc=com'. Basically how to search and retrieve user information is not working ... any ideas ... google has very slim documentation and even slimmer live examples

Comment: There is absolutely no need to set the base DN narrower than the domain components. Moreover, you need to chop off RDNs according to the base DN.

Comment: String searchFilter = "(&(cn=SmithK*))";String domain = "dc=xxxx,dc=com";
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); no results are found ... as if it does not care to search the organization which is A > Business, IT and under Business it is Management and IT it is Engineering and under engineering it is central engineering ... I am clueless at this point ...

Comment: Searching for a CN is logically wrong. They aren't unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use application.properties/application.yml to set properties

```
spring:
    ldap:
        urls: ldap://<address>:<port>
        base: <baseDN>
        username: <userDN>
        password: <password>
        pooled: true
```

Use a config class to define a bean with above properties

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource ctx = new LdapContextSource();
    ctx.setUrl(urls);
    ctx.setUserDn(username);
    ctx.setPassword(password);
    ctx.setPooled(pooled);
    ctx.afterPropertiesSet();
    return ctx;
}
```

Now build a LdapQuery and search using LdapTemplate

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)